# KDB + client connection using C#

Tags: c#, kdb

My requirement is to query the KDB using C#.NET. How to create a KDB client connection using C# provided you are having a host,port number and kerberos peer name ?

Comment: First port of call should always be http://code.kx.com/ - there's plenty of tutorials/guidelines for many languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to use exxeleron's qSharp, you can find:

- documentation for initializing the connection: https://github.com/exxeleron/qSharp/blob/master/doc/Connection.md
- sample code: https://github.com/exxeleron/qSharp/blob/master/doc/Usage-examples.md

Documentation for c.cs can be found on code.kx.com: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/InterfacingWithCSharp

Answer (score 1):

DevNet has something that might help you. Take a look at [qSharp](https://github.com/exxeleron/qSharp).